# How to group by two attributes in a list of objects using pyton

Tags: python, group-by

I have the following list:

```
my_list = [
            {
              'id': 1,
              'type': 'ventana',
              'test1': pass,
              'test2': fail
            },
            {
              'id': 2,
              'type': 'ventana',
              'test1': pass,
              'test2': pass
            },
            {
              'id': 3,
              'type': 'ventana',
              'test1': fail,
              'test2': fail
            }
          ]
```

I want to group by 'test1' and 'test2'.

I mean:

```
Objects who 'test1' = pass and 'test2' = pass  => One group
Objects who 'test1' = fail  or 'test2' = fail  => Other group
```

result should be something like:

```
result = [
           'GroupA': [
                       {
                         'id': 2,
                         'type': 'ventana',
                         'test1': pass,
                         'test2': pass
                       }
                     ],
           'GroupB': [
                       {
                         'id': 1,
                         'type': 'ventana',
                         'test1': pass,
                         'test2': fail
                       },
                       {
                         'id': 3,
                         'type': 'ventana',
                         'test1': fail,
                         'test2': fail
                       }
                     ]
         ]
```

I used Collections but it looks like I can evaluated just one attribute. I do not know how to evaluated both.

Comment: Terminology note: those are not attributes.

Comment: To be clear, you want anything with a fail to go in GroupB, and only those with two passes to go in GroupA? Also, **please always post valid Python example code**. Your code would throw a `NameError`, because `fail` is not defined, and indeed, just a SyntaxError because `pass` is a keyword, and cannot be an identifier.

Comment: `result` should also be a `dict`, not a `list`.

Answer (score 2):

One solution:

Note, that `fail` and `pass` should be strings or you will get syntax error

```
my_list = [
            {
              'id': 1,
              'type': 'ventana',
              'test1': "pass",
              'test2': "fail"
            },
            {
              'id': 2,
              'type': 'ventana',
              'test1': "pass",
              'test2': "pass"
            },
            {
              'id': 3,
              'type': 'ventana',
              'test1': "fail",
              'test2': "fail"
            }
          ]

res = {"A": [], "B": []}
for i in my_list:
    if i['test1'] == "fail" or i["test2"] == "fail":
        res["B"].append(i)
    else:
        res["A"].append(i)

print(res)
```

Output:

```
{'A': [{'id': 2, 'type': 'ventana', 'test1': 'pass', 'test2': 'pass'}], 'B': [{'id': 1, 'type': 'ventana', 'test1': 'pass', 'test2': 'fail'}, {'id': 3, 'type': 'ventana', 'test1': 'fail', 'test2': 'fail'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use `False` and `True` as indices - giving respectively `0` and `1` thus:

```
result = [[], []]
my_list = [
            {
              'id': 1,
              'type': 'ventana',
              'test1': 'pass',
              'test2': 'fail'
            },
            {
              'id': 2,
              'type': 'ventana',
              'test1': 'pass',
              'test2': 'pass'
            },
            {
              'id': 3,
              'type': 'ventana',
              'test1': 'fail',
              'test2': 'fail'
            }
          ]
for i in my_list:
    result[i['test1']=='pass' and i['test2']=='pass'].append(i)
print(result[0])  # with at least one fall
print(result[1])  # both pass
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 1, 'type': 'ventana', 'test1': 'pass', 'test2': 'fail'}, {'id': 3, 'type': 'ventana', 'test1': 'fail', 'test2': 'fail'}]
[{'id': 2, 'type': 'ventana', 'test1': 'pass', 'test2': 'pass'}]
```

Using `True` and `False` for indexing might looks tricky, but in my opinion is handy when you need to split `list` into 2 `list`s based on condition.

Answer (score 0):

Define the following classifier:

```
def p(d):
    if d['test1'] == 'pass' and d['test2'] == 'pass':
        return 'GroupA'
    else:
        return 'GroupB'
```

Then you can use `itertools.groupby` to build the desired result.

```
from itertools import groupby


result = {k: list(v) for k, v in groupby(sorted(my_list, key=p), p)}
```

The sorting order isn't important, as long as items destined for the same group are contiguous.

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(result)
{'GroupA': [{'id': 2, 'test1': 'pass', 'test2': 'pass', 'type': 'ventana'}],
 'GroupB': [{'id': 1, 'test1': 'pass', 'test2': 'fail', 'type': 'ventana'},
            {'id': 3, 'test1': 'fail', 'test2': 'fail', 'type': 'ventana'}]}
```